# Searching Text Files - High Scores (using Python)

Tags: python, text-files

Here is my code:

```
results = [[username, score]]

if (topic == 'history') and (difficulty == 'easy'):
    with open("hisEasyR.txt", "a") as hisEasyRFile:
        writer = csv.writer(hisEasyRFile, delimiter='|')
        writer.writerows(results)
```

This is what the text file looks like:

```
mary|4
john|5
lisa|3
```

I want to read from the file this file and find the highest score. Perhaps using the max function? I'm  not sure how to even go about this though. Is there a way to search a file like you can search a list?

Comment: You might want to start with `csv.reader` to get back rows of `(username, score)`. Once you have that, look again at the documentation of `max` and see if you can apply it.

Comment: @Ryan Sorry... I'm actually really unfamiliar with CVS. Another user helped me out with this part of code. How do you go about reading text files with CVS?

Comment: @Programmer12, if you are happy with one of the solutions below, can you accept one? This will help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I am doing it only using pure python

First you need to load the file

```
data = ""
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

You need so keep the best username and his score

```
best_username = ""
best_score = -1
```

Now go through each line

```
for line in data.split("\n"):
    username, score = line.split("|")  # reads user and his score from line
    if score > best_score:  # best user we encounterd so far
        best_username = username
        best_score = score
```

The result is in best_username. This gets you first user with the highest score

```
mary|4
john|5
lisa|3
dana|5
```

returns john

## EDIT:

there may be blank line at the end of file, to ignore it use:

```
for line in data.split("\n"):
    if "|" not in line:  # skips invalid lines
        continue
    username, score = line.split("|")  # reads user and his score from line
    if score > best_score:  # best user we encounterd so far
        best_username = username
        best_score = score
```

## EDIT 2:

You need to convert score to int, should have tested my code

```
for line in data.split("\n"):
    if "|" not in line:  # skips invalid lines
        continue
    username, score = line.split("|")  # reads user and his score from line
    score = int(score)
    if score > best_score:  # best user we encounterd so far
        best_username = username
        best_score = score
```

Comment: This sounds like a great approach! I've tried it out but it gives me this error: `username, score = line.split("|")  # reads user and his score from line
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: Yeh, sorry, i forgot that csv writer do \n at the end (there is blank line, so it cannot be split)

Comment: Aren't scores compared as strings, which would make 4 > 11?

Comment: Yes, Sorry! I shoud have tryed my code before posting, you need to make score int.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a clean interface for this kind of task:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath, delimiter='|', header=None, names=['username', 'score'])

highest_score = df['score'].max()
highest_score_username = df.loc[df['score'] == highest_score, 'username']
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. Is Pandas a Python 3 module? :)

Comment: No, pandas does work with python 2.7. It is not a built-in function on module that ships with python as standard. However, it is open source, freely available, well documented, and ships with almost all distributions such as Anaconda, ActivePython, Canopy, etc.

Comment: Okay so how do I go about getting it to work on my computer? Do I download it or something?

Comment: For python 2.7, the steps are described here: http://viziblr.com/news/2012/4/21/step-by-step-installing-pandas-on-windows-7-from-pypi-with-e.html

However, first check you don't have it installed. Run the script. If it errors on `import pandas as pd` you know it's not installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use pandas to read your file as a dataFrame and then convert it to an array or list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('hisEasyR.txt', sep='|', header=None)
print("scores array:", x[1])
print("minimum score:", min(x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't need to use a csvwriter for a simple txt file.

```
l = []
with open("hisEasyR.txt", "ab+") as hisEasyRFile:
   for line in hisEasyRFile.read().splitlines():
      if line != '\n':
         l.append([line.split('|')[0], int(line.split('|')[1])])

l.sort(key=lambda element: element[1])
print(l[-1])
```